# Video editing software for easy freeze frame voiceover

Tags: audio

I'm currently using Movie Studio Platinum 16. When I need to make a voiceover (e.g. for a product presentation), I like to do it without a carefully planned script, just talking over the video and pausing the video when necessary to manually sync the video with the narrative. However, in Movie Studio Platinum 16 it's not possible, so I end up either rushing my voiceover or having to manually edit freeze frames afterwards.

Which video editing software allows doing voiceover to a video and "live" pause the video but continue recording audio in sync with the paused video?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this in both Adobe Premier and Final Cut Pro. Here's some links:

https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/recording-audio.html

https://support.apple.com/guide/final-cut-pro/record-voiceovers-verc1faa9c5/mac